# Rails 5 + Puma + Pow not working locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, ruby-on-rails-5, pow.cx

I'm updating my rails app to `5.0.0.rc1` in a separate branch. App was already configured to run on `puma 2.14`, but I upgraded to `puma 3.4.0` during the update process.

I ran `rails update` but kept my old puma config around because nothing changed except the `plugins` directive which I don't care about now.

Anyway, I cannot get my app to respond in development mode, **but I deployed it a staging server to see if I could get better error logs and it actually works on staging**.

Before, I could access my app locally using pow by visiting:

```
http://app.dev
```

Now, that doesn't work. Neither does:

```
bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb config.ru
```

Nor does this:

```
bin/rails server puma
```

My logs just show something like this everytime:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-27 09:11:39 -0400
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-27 09:11:44 -0400
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-27 09:11:47 -0400
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-27 09:11:50 -0400
```

They never make it to Rails for processing no matter how I attempt to start the server locally. And that's all the error info I get, too. Pow's logs are similarly useless.

Any ideas whats going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The emotional successor of pow(latest commit on the repo is from 6 November 2014) is [puma-dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev). According to their docs  pow is a no-go for Rails 5. Maybe you should give it a go.